# Caveats when upgrading from Java 6 to Java 7 on hundreds of production servers

Tags: java

I am about to upgrade the [JDK version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) from Java 1.6.0_37-b06 to Java 1.7.0_11.64 in a few hundreds of production servers, which run Tomcat servlets. The upgrade is a part of a large system upgrade [from RHEL 5 to RHEL 6](https://serverfault.com/questions/473823/caveats-when-upgrading-from-rhel-5-4-to-rhel-6-3-on-hundreds-of-production-serve).

The upgrade will be tested on a staging environment on virtual machines before production deployment.

Are there any known Backward-compatibility issues between these two versions?

Comment: What OS? What version?

Comment: RHEL - updated my question.

Comment: Here be dragons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment on the codebase running within Tomcat but we're running Tomcat 6 with Java 7 and there are no issues; the developers, however, need to conduct their own readiness tests. There a few housekeeping items to consider though such as

- Custom certificates in the keystore that need to be transferred to the new JDK
- Custom entries in the java.policy file? E.g. JMX options
- Custom entries in java.security e.g. we adjust the DNS TTL in this file

Configuration management tools like Chef/Puppet can assist in this regard.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using a in-house configuration management tool, and my chief concern is software package compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

I've never had issues with Java 6 to Java 7... I typically did the move via the OpenJDK packaging to make sure `/etc/alternatives` and all symlinks were updated properly. You're going to have a *much* bigger issue with the mechanics of the EL5 to EL6 move, though.