# Caveats when upgrading from RHEL 5.4 to RHEL 6.3 on hundreds of production servers

Tags: rhel5, rhel6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Caveats when upgrading from Java 6 to Java 7 on hundreds of production servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/473822/caveats-when-upgrading-from-java-6-to-java-7-on-hundreds-of-production-servers)

I am about to upgrade the RHEL version from RHEL 5.4 to RHEL 6.3 in a few hundreds of production servers.

The upgrade will be tested on a staging environment on virtual machines before production deployment.

Are there any backward-compatibility issues with RHEL upgrades?

Comment: Are you performing ***in-place*** upgrades? If so, please see: [**Why is it so difficult to upgrade between major versions of Red Hat and CentOS?**](http://serverfault.com/questions/449048/why-is-it-so-difficult-to-upgrade-between-major-versions-of-red-hat-and-centos)

Comment: It's not in-place. The server is re-installed, and the existing software packages - in-house and external open source tools - are installed on the new operating system, so I guess my main concern is software package compatibility.

Comment: @AdamMatan This is your environment, so you'll have to test the software side. I've given some general advice about basic differences, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't run the upgrade process this way *if* you're planning to perform in-place transitions from EL5 to EL6. It's not an easy or clean process.

See: [Why is it so difficult to upgrade between major versions of Red Hat and CentOS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449048/why-is-it-so-difficult-to-upgrade-between-major-versions-of-red-hat-and-centos) and [Upgrade CentOS 5.x to CentOS 6.x - tips and techniques](https://serverfault.com/questions/288792/upgrade-centos-5-x-to-centos-6-x-tips-and-techniques)

However, you have the right idea of testing this in a limited-capacity first.

Regardless of deployment technique, the biggest issues I saw in moving from EL5 to EL6 were:

- Dealing with deprecated packages
- Needing a much larger `/boot` partition (from 100Mb to 300Mb)
- A large amount of [performance tuning](https://serverfault.com/questions/387918/centos-6-doing-lots-more-io-than-centos-5) needed to deal with the newer scheduling algorithms, different kernel and `sysctl` defaults, etc.
- Learning about the [tuned-adm framework](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/tuned-adm.html). Also see: [Openfiler iSCSI performance](https://serverfault.com/questions/430955/openfiler-iscsi-performance/431112#431112)